# Unable to download jenkins-core jar using Grapes

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I am writing a groovy script and trying to download jenkins-core module using Grapes but I am not able to.

```
@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.9')
])
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
```

It is giving me following error:

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.jenkins-ci.main#jenkins-core;2.9: not found]

java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.jenkins-ci.main#jenkins-core;2.9: not found]

I have tried other versions also but it didn't work. These version are available in maven repo. I would really appreciate if you could help me resolving the issue.

Comment: It does not seam to be available in central maven repo: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cjenkins-core

Comment: Can you please guide me which jar can I download for jenkins module

Answer (score 2):

As `jenkins-core` is not available in maven central but in `jenkins-ci` maven repository, you need to add `http://repo.jenkins-ci.org` repository.

**Grape**

```
@GrabResolver(name='jenkins', root='http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/')
@Grab(group='org.jenkins-ci.main', module='jenkins-core', version='2.9')
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
```

**Note**: You need to be using groovy version `2.4.7` or higher to be able to grab `jenkins-core` due to this fixed groovy [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7833)

**Gradle**

Add a new maven repository for `jenkins-ci.org` and the `jenkins-core` dependency

```
repositories {

    ...       

    maven {
        url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/public/'
    }
}

dependencies {

    ... 

    compile group: 'org.jenkins-ci.main', name: 'jenkins-core', version: '2.9'
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer with build.gradle

Comment: I'm not using Gradle, I'm adding Groovy code to Maven using the Jenkins Pipeline plugin. I've added your Grape lines and I'm getting this error: `Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: org.jenkins-ci.main#jenkins-core;2.9: not found]` Any idea how to resolve the dependencies?